# Is it safe to use pre-defined collectors in parallel streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I wonder, is it thread-safe to use pre-defined collectors (like `Collectors.toSet`, `Collectors.toList`) on parallel streams, which are created using `collection.parallelStream()` method?

Or one has to use custom synchronized collector, like this?

```
collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())))
```

Comment: you are right, but the question was title so specific i could not find it - will try to edit the original